# Update GridViewRow on button click of that row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I have a `GridView` with `checkbox`, `dropdown` and `button` as templatefields.
On button click I have to update the entire row in the data base.

This is my `aspx`:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Gdv" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Font-Size="Small" CssClass="grid" BackColor="White" BorderWidth="0px" CellPadding="4" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" SkinID="GVSalesManager" GridLines="none" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" PagerStyle-ForeColor="#0066cc" PagerStyle-CssClass="gvPagerCss" PagerStyle-Font-Underline="true" PagerStyle-Wrap="true"
OnPageIndexChanging="GdvCPRetailerMap_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="GdvCPRetailerMap_RowDataBound">
 <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="S.No" DataField="S.No." SortExpression="SNo">
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="2%" />
     <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="true"  Width="2%"/>
    </asp:BoundField>

   <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="3%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="chkRow_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>

   <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Customer Id" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="CustomerID" SortExpression="CustomerID">
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="true"  Width="10%"/>
   </asp:BoundField>

 <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Firm's Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="Firm's Name" SortExpression="SNo">
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="20%" />
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="true"  Width="20%"/>
  </asp:BoundField>

 <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Retailer Name" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="Retialer Name" SortExpression="SNo">
  <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="20%" />
  <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="true"  Width="20%"/>
 </asp:BoundField>

 <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Pesticide Licence No." ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataField="Pesticide Licence No" SortExpression="SNo">
 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
 <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="true"  Width="10%"/>
 </asp:BoundField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Channel Partner-1" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCP1" Enabled="false" ToolTip="Please Click on the checkbox to change the prefered CP" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCP1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Channel Partner-2" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCP2" Enabled="false" ToolTip="Please Click on the checkbox to change the prefered CP" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCP2_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

 <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="BtnUpdateRow" Text="Update" ToolTip="Update This Record?" OnClick="BtnUpdateRow_Click" BackColor="#336699" ForeColor="#ffffff"/>
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>

  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is the `updatebutton` event

```
protected void BtnUpdateRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    GridViewRow grow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
    //btn.
    CheckBox chkbx = (CheckBox)grow.FindControl("chkRow");

    if (chkbx.Checked != true)
    {
        labelErrormessage.Visible = true;
        labelErrormessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        labelErrormessage.Text = "Please Check/Uncheck the CheckBox and Click Update";
        return;

    }
    else 
    {
        /*--Code to update the row's record in the edatabase.--*/
        ??

        labelErrormessage.Visible = true;
        labelErrormessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        labelErrormessage.Text = "Updated Succesfully";
        return;
    }
}
```

How do I read the row in which the button has been clicked and update its `dropdownlist` selected values in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some sort of identification data displayed in the gridview you could get the value from the row's cell like this `grow.Cells[0].Text` then find the record in the database and update its values.

You could also hide the id for example if this is information you dont want to show to the user. The row will still be located at index 0 but hidden.

**Sample:**

```
    else 
    {
        var record = queryDatabase(grow.Cells[0].Text);

        //update record values

        updateRecord(record);

        labelErrormessage.Visible = true;
        labelErrormessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        labelErrormessage.Text = "Updated Succesfully";
        return;
    }
```